# Uploading multiple DS18B20 values to Xively Newbie Alert

Tags: xively

i am having problmes getting this code to upload the channel id and values to xively, can someone offer me some guidance on where i am going wrong?

```
 temp = read_temp()
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"SolarFlow","current_value":temp_0}]})
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"SolarReturn","current_value":temp_1}]})
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"BufferIn","current_value":temp_2}]})
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"BufferOut","current_value":temp_3}]})
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"UFH_Flow","current_value":temp_4}]})
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"GSHP_Flow","current_value":temp_5}]})
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"GSHP_WellReturn","current_value":temp_6}]})
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"GSHP_LoopsReturn","current_value":temp_7}]})
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"HotWaterTank","current_value":temp_8}]})
    data = json.dumps({"version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"HotWaterPreHeatTank","current_value":temp_9}]})

    with open("temp.tmp", "w") as f:
        f.write(data)

    subprocess.call(['curl --request PUT --data-binary @temp.tmp --header "X-ApiKey: AR4soQUW2uG3t2pTVl3FVPPKZPfH66tJ0Z8SjBlEzhvFXpIK" http://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/2002766727'], shell=True)

    os.remove("temp.tmp")
```

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this will be using [official Python module](http://xively.github.io/xively-python/) provided by Xively.

Here are few reasons for not doing it the way you just described:

1. the official library provides a nice and simple API
2. you don't need to care what the data format actually is
3. calling curl command to make an HTTP request every 
   time is absolutely inefficient as it take time for the OS
   to spawn and new process